# How to specify installdir for ActivePython 2.7.13

Tags: activepython

I don't understand why the MSI installers are gone for ActivePython, but they are, and it broke an unattended install setup on Windows.  I need to have 32 and 64-bit versions installed and specifying INSTALLDIR, TARGETDIR, DEFAULTALLUSERSTARGETDIR doesn't work; the path stays at the default of c:\Python27 for both 32 and 64-bit installs.

I also pulled the MSI from c:\windows\installers and tried that approach, but the MSI reports it requires a bootstrapper to be used.

Has anyone had success with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the parameter is now called APPDIR which is referenced in the documentation (http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/get/windows/index.html). The documentation does still refer to the MSI, however the new .EXE installer is just a wrapper on the MSI, so existing MSI parameters like `/qn` for silent install still work.

If you'd like to install the 64-bit into its own folder for example, you can use:

```
ActivePython-2.7.13.2714-win64-x64-402182.exe APPDIR="C:\Python27-64"
```

Hope that helps!